# $\langle x | p \rangle = \psi_p(x)$ , What this anything to do with $\psi$ (Notation in R.Shankar)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, momentum, wavefunction, notation

In Principal of Quantum Mechanics R.Shankar Page 137

if we project the eigenvalue equation
$$P|p\rangle = p|p\rangle$$
onto the $X $ basis,we get
$$\langle x|P|p\rangle = p \langle  x |p \rangle$$
or,
$$-i\frac{h}{2\pi}\frac{d\psi_p(x)}{dx}=p\psi_p(x) $$
where, $$\psi_p(x)=\langle x |p \rangle.$$
They use the notation $\psi_p(x)$ for $\langle x |p \rangle$ , I know it is just a notation but $\psi$ has noting to do with  $\langle x |p \rangle$ and $p$ is labeled in $\psi(x)$(=$\langle x|\psi \rangle$ ) which is continuous.
The same is used in page 313 for $\langle x| l_z \rangle $ equating it to $\psi_{l_z}(\rho,\phi)$.

Comment: Is your question why $p$ is a subscript even though it's a continuous variable, or is your question why is $\psi_p(x) = <x|p>$?

Comment: The first one ,also want to know why they use notation $\psi_p(x)$ for $\langle x|p \rangle$ because this has nothing to do with $\psi$.

Comment: In the context of this question $\psi_p(x)$ is taken to be a momentum eigenstate. That is,  it is *defined* to be $\langle x |p \rangle$.   There's no reason why a subscript can't represent a continuous variable.

Answer (score 4):

You have an important mistake. 
\begin{align}
\langle x|P|p\rangle &\neq p \langle  x \rangle \\
 & = p \langle x|p\rangle \\
 & = p \frac{e^{ipx/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\\
 & = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{e^{ipx/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
\end{align}

Now, for what you're missing is that $\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$ for *any* wave function (state) $\psi(x)$ ($|\psi\rangle$). In this case, the state in question is $|p\rangle$ with the wave function is $\psi_p(x)$ (don't overlook the subscript!).

Comment: $\psi_p(x)$ is a probability amplitude that the position eigenstate $\psi(x)$ have momentum p.  Momentum is continuous so why they use subscript.

Comment: @HimanshuSahu Incorrect. They are defining $\psi_p(x) = \langle x | p\rangle$. $\psi(x)$ is not a position eigenstate, it's a generic state of any sort. $\psi_p(x)$ is not meant to have $p$ as a discrete subscript, it's just a label (like $k_B$ for Boltzmann's constant) to let you know that you have the (denormalized) probability amplitude of a momentum eigenstate to be at position $x$. Similarly, $\psi_x(p) = \langle p|x\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

A (wave-)function $\psi$ in a Hilbert space, is in fact a vector with infinitely many components. In bra-ket notation we write it as $|\psi \rangle$. Instead the complex number $\psi(x)$ is the component of the vector in the (overcomplete) basis $|x\rangle$ which is the position basis. Such wavefunction represents a particle sitting at position $x$ with certainty. So its components themselves must be

$$
\langle x' | x \rangle = \delta(x'-x).
$$

The number $\psi(x)$, formally, is also the scalar product of $|x\rangle$ with $|\psi\rangle$. Indeed, again formally,

$$
\langle x | \psi\rangle = \int dx' \delta(x'-x) \psi(x') = \psi(x). 
$$

In its book Shankar simply uses the (common) notation $|p\rangle$ for the wavefunction $\psi_p$ since he knows it depends on the quantum number $p$.